# How does CSS flex-basis affect the width calculation of its container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following example, the `flex-basis: 30px` and `width: 30px` of a flex item will result in different container width(flex-basis is shorter).

How does `flex-basis` affect its parent width in the following example:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.grand {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.flex1 {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* added according to Michael_B's answer */
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex1">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item flex2">22222 222222222</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The is the expected behavior:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.grand {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.flex1 {
  /* flex-basis: 100px; */
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grand">
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex1">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item flex2">22222 222222222</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the `flex-basis` version, the `flex2` item will wrap the text, while the `width` version will not. How did that happen.